# C++ builder TstringGrid get string from specific cell

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl, tstringgrid

Hello everybody i have C++ tStringGrid

I want to get string from specific cell with coordinates

I have tried this but without luck:

```
UnicodeString cell_obj = StringGrid1->Objects[3][2]->ToString();
```

Error:

```
Access violation at address 00407617 in module 'NGG_Client.exe'. Read of address 00000000.
```

Please help.

Comment: Do you know how big the grid is?  ie: is 3,2 out of bounds?

Comment: @Zac: the address it is reading is a NULL pointer. Likely the cell referenced is uninitialized.

Comment: @user525717: Can you show us what ColCount and RowCount are at runtime? Perhaps Objects[3,2] is null, or show us more about StringGrid1 (which may be NULL as well).

Comment: Do you mean this objects? >>> Form1->StringGrid1->Cells[1][i] = name.c_str();
    Form1->StringGrid1->Cells[2][i] = address.c_str();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a working dev enviroment up that can build this but try:

```
assert( StringGrid1->ColCount > 3 && StringGrid1->RowCount > 2 );
UnicodeString cell_str = StringGrid1->Cells[3][2];
```

It might be an `AnsiString` instead of a `UnicodeString`.

Comment: Also StringGrid1 could be null.

Comment: its a good idea to put the assert in there too - just to check your codes assumptions.  Could also include `StringGrid1 != nullptr` from @sixlettervariables in the assert.